# Call Web Services from Windows Service

Tags: c#

I created a Web Service where I take data from a database and insert
them into a list of string type. This web service is called from a
Windows Service that receives the list and retrieving the data. To do
this I added the reference to the Windows Service, but I do not know
if I get the list from the Web Service correctly. This is the code of
the windows service:

```
    RicDati ricdati = new RicDati();
    var listas = ricdati.PrelevaDati().Count();
    List<string> lista = new List<string>();
    lista.AddRange(ricdati.PrelevaDati());
```

`RicDati` is the class of the Web Service, `PrelevaDati` is the name of the method

Comment: And what specifically is not working?

Comment: When I start the Windows Service I don't know if it receives data from the Web Service.

Comment: What that supposed to mean, you don't know? Create a trace file and trace if the data received or not.

Answer (score 1):

Before running it in a Service, run/debug the parts which are not service related in a console application.

1. Create a library project of your business processes which the service will use, but also the console application. This will contain the call to the webservices.
2. Test the process in the console without having the unknowns of a service.
3. Once the processes are working then run it in the service.

Answer (score 1):

I think is more a matter of debugging your windows service, sometimes this could be very difficult but ic an suggest a workarround.

Practically you need to create a console application or windows that practically is going to create and call a windows service instance without even intall it on your computar, this practically feels like you're debugging a normal windows application.

this is a project that uses a winform to debug win services I'm more into a consolo (because I feel it's easier), but the concept is the same so you can take a look.
[enter link description here](http://windowsservicehelper.codeplex.com/)

the main code practically is the following:

﻿using System.ServiceProcess;
using ServiceProcess.Helpers;

```
namespace DemoService
{
    static class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        static void Main()
        {
            ServiceBase[] ServicesToRun;

            ServicesToRun = new ServiceBase[] 
            { 
                new Service1() 
            };

            //ServiceBase.Run(ServicesToRun);
            ServicesToRun.LoadServices();
        }
    }
}
```